# Make a class dependency appear in interface without it being a property

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

I have an interface and a class that implements that interface.

I have a requirement that the class has a dependency on ITimer. A private member is created and a constructor argument is passed in and the private member is assigned to that constructor parameter.

How do I make it so that the interface has this ITimer declared somehow but not as a property? Its not as if I can't test MyClass properly but I thought the interface was supposed to be a contract that the class must adhere to therefore my class has a dependency so how do I make this appear in the interface?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
  void DoSomething();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
  private ITimer MyTimer;

  public MyClass(ITimer timer)
  {
    MyTimer = timer;
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to have the interface enforce that all implementing classes have a constructor that takes an `ITimer`, is that right? (you won't be able to do this with an interface, btw)

Comment: Not technically the answer to the posed question, but as a solution to your problem. How about defining MyClassBase (an abstract base class/type) and coding against it (vs an interface) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with an interface in C#. What you could do is to inherit from an abstract class instread of an interface.

```
public abstract class AMyClass
{
  protected ITimer MyTimer;

  public AMyClass(ITimer timer)
  {
    MyTimer = timer;
  }

  public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class MyClass : AMyClass
{
  public override void DoSomething()
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes -- this is the correct answer for what the asker is looking for. An interface cannot define how an object is constructed because it -- by definition -- does not define the implementation. However, one thing to remember is that it's OK to have an implementation that doesn't look just like the interface because the interface is just for consumers. So, either go with a base abstract class -- that can even inherit from the interface -- or keep the implementation different. If you have any questions let us know.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work, and it is good, that it will not work:

Your dependency on `ITimer` is not part of the **interface**, it is part of your **implementation** of the interface - so having this hidden from the interface is the right thing.

If ALL implementations of the interface need a dependency on `ITimer` (and **only** if so), then your interface declaration should be appended to care for that.

Comment: And how would you do that without making the dependency a property?

Comment: This ofcourse depends on waht your code does, but I'd probaly go with parameter-less constructor and a `setTimer()` method that is part of the interface.

Comment: I think an ITimer in the constructor is still appropriate but having a method in the interface called SetTimer() is a good idea as it shows that a timer is required. It obviosuly doesnt expose ITimer as a interface dependency but maybe its one step closer to ensure all class implementations use a timer

Comment: Again, without insight of what the code really does, I don't have a solid base to judge from.

Comment: Well for example if the interface has a UseTimer property and in the DoSomething method if its true it sets up a timer

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dependency such as `ITimer` that you explicitly don't want on the interface, then it sounds like an implementation detail, so it is *correct* that it isn't defined as part of the contract. One approach is "forget about `ITimer`; only some implementations might need it, and that is the concern of an IoC/DI resolver".

Constructors are not part of the interface, obviously. The only other thing I can think of (while keeping `IMyInterface` off the API) is to have an `IMyInterfaceFactory` interface, with a `Create` method that takes an `ITimer` - but that is then forcing a **particular set of** dependencies, which may not reflect the actual implementations.

If none of the above suite, and `ITimer` is *essentially* part of the interface, I'd make it **formally** part of the interface.

Comment: If you make it part of the interface though, you make it public and you wouldn't want to allow users to change parts of ITimer. Saying that you may need to expose properties like Interval so I guess if you make visible some things then I guess it may be ok to expose the whole timer

Comment: @Jon the internals of `ITimer` I leave entirely to `ITimer`. You don't show how it is defined, so I can't commend on anything about it.

Comment: At the moment it exposes all properties of System.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 2):

Why is property not appropriate? You can have a property with a private setter which does exactly what you need, it seems.

Other option is to derive both from an abstract base class with protected Timer and implement the interface at the same time.

Theoretically Dependency Injection is what you are looking for. So may be having a look at Inversion of Control containers might be worth the time.

Comment: If you had a private setter in the class it would not implement the interface as it has to be public. The abstract class I guess is the correct answer though

Comment: Why don't you want to add smth like this?                   interface IMyInterface
    {
        int ITimer MyTimer { get; }
    }

    internal class MyClass  IMyInterface
    {
        public ITimer MyTimer { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a contract to a *capability* that a class exposes. If there's no natural place for `ITimer` in the interface, then it looks like an *implementation detail* in a specific class that implements it, and as such, should remain in the class.

Answer (score 0):

If a class can implement your interface without using `ITimer`, does it not adhere to the interface? It obviously does.

The use of `ITimer` is an implementation detail, and so it shouldn't be represented in the interface.